# FacebookException: Failed to get app name

Tags: facebook, react-native, fbsdk

I'm trying to share some content from my react-native app on facebook. The share activity opens and than close with this error response `Failed to get app name`.

This is my AndroidManifest.xml file

```
<meta-data android:name="com.facebook.sdk.ApplicationId" android:value="@string/facebook_app_id"/>
  <activity
    android:name="com.facebook.FacebookActivity"
    android:configChanges="keyboard|keyboardHidden|screenLayout|screenSize|orientation"
    android:label="@string/app_name" />
  <activity android:name="com.facebook.react.devsupport.DevSettingsActivity" />
  <provider
    android:name="com.facebook.FacebookContentProvider"
    android:authorities="com.facebook.app.FacebookContentProvider${facebook_app_id}"
    android:exported="true" />
```

I'm using `react-native 0.55.2` and `react-native-fbsdk 0.7.0`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I had encountered the same issue, the error message shown is not correct.

Your facebook app should be **logged in** with the user that has the **facebook roles** as mentioned [here](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/v2.12/app/roles)

- Admin
- Developer
- Test